# different methods for a collection in a view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I'm looking into backboneJS and I'm trying to figure out when to use the collection attribute and when to use this.collection inside the initialize function? Is there a difference? Here is an example.

```
Backbone.View.extend({
collection: myCollection,

initialize: function(collectionData) {
  this.collection = new app.Library(collectionData);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use "this" in a method of a object, it is set to the object the method called on. So this.collection will always equal to collection property (initialize method will be invoked by a view instance right?).

In my opinion, I always assign the default collection in view option declaration and access the collection reference by this.collection in the method of view object.

```
//set the default collection to a view object
var CustomView = Backbone.View.extend({
    collection: myCollection
});

//or set collection when you instantitate a view
var myView = new CustomView({collection: myCollection});

//and get the reference of view's collection for event registering
initialize:function(){
  //refresh view when new data is added to collection
  this.listenTo(this.collection,"add",this.render);
}
```